# How to get images photo gallery?

Tags: sql, asp.net, arrays, eval

I want to do an image gallery, but photos are not coming from the database.

I can only see one picture whereas it should have many different photos...

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /><%#Eval("resim") %> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

---

```
SqlConnection cnn = klas.baglan();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" Select * from aracResimler where ilanID="+ID, cnn);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    Image[] imageArray = new Image[dr.FieldCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i++)
    {
        imageArray[i] = new Image();

        imageArray[i].ImageUrl = "~/Resimler/800/" + dr[2].ToString();
        //Response.Write(imageArray[i].ImageUrl);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(imageArray[i]);
    }
}
```

How do I ask about to  get images into a photo gallery?

Comment: It's not really clear what this code is supposed to be doing.  But it looks like you're setting an array of images to the same value each time (`dr[2].ToString()`).  Is that what you meant to do?  When you step through this in a debugger, where *specifically* does it fail?

Comment: Yes sir, I am setting an array of images to the same value each time (dr[2].ToString()). there is no any debugger, that's why I don't know where I am missing something

Comment: Are you certain that you have more than one row in the table `aracResimler` with `ilanID` equial to `3043`?

Comment: Yes sir, I am certain. also I can see them this message show ""Response.Write(imageArray[i].ImageUrl);""